# How to modify object from Swing in jME3?

Tags: java, swing, jmonkeyengine

I was rotating my jME3 scene object from Swing program. Unfortunately, rotations does not occur until I click jME3 canvas by mouse.

Is it possible to implement modifications immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Is a question a long time ago and you have probably already found a solution.
I had the same problem and searched very hard for an solution.

For those who have the same problem, here is a link that might help.

http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/swing-canvas-and-events/21352/2

Conclusion:
It is a problem of the lost focus in JME canvas.

**You can solve it with 2 line code!**

**First:** choose on appsetting: `setPauseOnLostFocus(false);`

- this make your update methode run also when lost the focus, by clicking on swing components

**Second:** Also set the focusable property for the other controls in the windows to false with: `object.setFocusable(false);`

I hope I could help.
Best regards.

EsKay.